# How to populate a table in excel using variables for cell (x,y) values

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching stack over flow constantly for the past few weeks as i learn excel vb but finally I'm stumped.

I need to activate a cell using a variable for the x location and a variable for the y location.

The xval is an integer 
yval is a string

I'm trying to use the match function to do this with no luck.

Here's what I've tried.

```
Sheets("Attributes").Select      'this is the sheet with the raw data
Range("C2").Activate
Dim xval As String                'this is the row I'm looking for
Dim yval As Integer               'this is the colum I'm looking for
Dim value As String               'when I find the exact right cell on the next sheet this is the value that needs to go in it.

' start loop here

xval = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)   'populate variables
yval = ActiveCell
value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
Sheets("output").Select              'switch to output sheet
Range("A1").Activate

Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(xval, "A:A", 0), WorksheetFunction.Match(yval, "A1:A500", 0)).Activate    'this line doesn't work


ActiveCell = value

'end loop when data runs out using is empty function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim xval As String
    Dim yval As Integer
    Dim v As String
    Dim shtOut As Worksheet
    Dim f As Range

    Set shtOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("output")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Attributes").Range("C2")
        xval = .Offset(0, -2).value
        yval = .value
        v = .Offset(0, 2).value
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Set f = shtOut.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(xval, shtOut.Range("A:A"), 0), _
                      WorksheetFunction.Match(yval, shtOut.Range("A1:A500"), 0))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not f Is Nothing Then f.value = v

    'flag if not found
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Attributes").Range("C2").Font.Color = _
                               IIf(f Is Nothing, vbRed, vbGreen)


End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, when I run your code I get a "subscript out of range" error on the line.     Set shtOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("output")

I also swapped my string and integer variables, they were backwards when posted.

Comment: If you get that error then there's no sheet with that name in the workbook containing the macro. If instead you want it to operate on the active workbook (not necessarily the one with the macro in it) then use `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook`